# Plot ggplot2 figures to multiple jpg's with file named as subject ID

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a large number of patient data that I'd like to use to produce health reports for. I'd like to produce one file for each patient with the file name being the subject ID.

The data looks like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)

set.seed(3344)
subject_id <- as.factor(1:10)
var1 <- rnorm(n = length(subject_id), mean = 100, sd = 12)
var2 <- rnorm(n = length(subject_id), mean = 50, sd = 10)
var3 <- rnorm(n = length(subject_id), mean = 200, sd = 100)
df <- data.frame(subject_id, var1, var2, var3)

df <- df %>%
    melt(., id.vars = "subject_id", measure.vars = c(2:4))
```

I've done this once before, producing a pdf file that had one subject per page, however with our new system we need the files in .jpg format, one file per subject, and each file named the subject ID. When doing this to the large PDF file I did it like this:

```
plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = variable)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = 0.8)) +
    facet_wrap(~subject_id)

library(plyr)

pdf("Plot Example.pdf")
dlply(df, .(subject_id), function(x) plot %+% x)
dev.off()
```

However, I'm stuck as to how to produce each subject as a single file, with their ID as the file name, and the file type to be a .jpg. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Rather than `pdf/dev.off` try using `ggsave()`. Include it to the function you are passing to `dlply`. Or you could also move the `pdf/dev.off` inside that function as well.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried to add the `ggsave()` function to the `dlply` call I'm making, however no matter where I add it I get an error: `dlply(df, .(subject_id), function(ggsave(x)) plot %+% x)`. Within `ggsave()` I know I can specify that I want a `.jepg` however this wouldn't solve the issue of printing one file per subject with each file name being the subject ID. Or would it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very familiar with `dlply`, but you can try the following:

```
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)

plotdf <- function(i){
    g = ggplot(i, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = variable)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = 0.8)) 
    ggsave(g,file=paste0(unique(i$subject_id),".png"))
}

df %>% split(.$subject_id) %>% map(plotdf)
```